# How to select date from a time range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In our Postgres database, we have the following range for a field:

The value looks like this: (some kind of a slot)

```
["2015-02-06 18:30:00","2015-02-06 19:00:00")
```

We would like out of it to select only the first component: `2015-02-06`

We tried several functions: `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`, `TO Char` but they are all giving errors.

Any idea how we could solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get the date from timestamp you should cast timestamp  to date using ::date

```
SELECT your_timestamp_column::date FROM table_name  
where your_timestamp_column::date='date'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I am gonna use it for several other fields!

Comment: you are welcome, would you please recomonde this answer

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the table definition but it seems that your column is a `tsrange`.

You need to extract the lower element of the range which gives you a timestamp and then cast that to a date:

```
select lower(the_column)::date
from the_table;
```

See the manual for more details:

- [Range Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)
- [Range Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

Comment: I will ask you an additional question because I really want to understand! We have to different field: on is like this 2015-01-27 13:35:51.905 and to separate we used the formula to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'FMDD.MM.YYYY')  What is the difference with lower ? I check your documentation but I couldn't find the answer... Thank you!